# CSS Opacity error in W3C Validator

Tags: javascript, css

I need to W3C CSS Validator logo for my website. Due to some error I m not getting it.
I need your help to get them logo.
Here is W3C Error List

`100  .jdGallery a.right, .jdGallery a.left  Parse Error opacity=20)
100  .jdGallery a.right, .jdGallery a.left  Property -moz-opacity doesn't exist : 0.2 0.2
100  .jdGallery a.right, .jdGallery a.left  Property -khtml-opacity doesn't exist : 0.2 0.2
100  .jdGallery a.right, .jdGallery a.left  Property opacity doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : 0.2 0.2
103  * html .jdGallery a.right, * html .jdGallery a.left  Parse Error opacity=50)
106  .jdGallery a.right:hover, .jdGallery a.left:hover  Parse Error opacity=80)
106  .jdGallery a.right:hover, .jdGallery a.left:hover  Property -moz-opacity doesn't exist : 0.8 0.8
106  .jdGallery a.right:hover, .jdGallery a.left:hover  Property -khtml-opacity doesn't exist : 0.8 0.8
106  .jdGallery a.right:hover, .jdGallery a.left:hover  Property opacity doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : 0.8 0.8
122  .withArrows a.open  Property -moz-opacity doesn't exist : 0.8 0.8
122  .withArrows a.open  Property -khtml-opacity doesn't exist : 0.8 0.8
122  .withArrows a.open  Property opacity doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : 0.8 0.8
127  * html .withArrows a.open:hover  Parse Error opacity=80)
148  .jdGallery a.gallerySelectorBtn  Property opacity doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : 0.4 0.4
149  .jdGallery a.gallerySelectorBtn  Property -moz-opacity doesn't exist : 0.4 0.4
150  .jdGallery a.gallerySelectorBtn  Property -khtml-opacity doesn't exist : 0.4 0.4
151  .jdGallery a.gallerySelectorBtn  Parse Error opacity=40)`

I think all errors are same. The problem is only one opacity.

Please send me your inputs how to resolve these errors and get validate logo.

Thanks
Rakesh Prajapati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `-moz-opacity,-khtml-opacity` they are not valid on W3c validator.. remove them and check

Answer (score 0):

The way to do opacity in IE < 9 is via the non-standard `filter` property (it uses a Direct X filter)...there's not much you can do here, if you want opacity in IE.

If it helps, it's complaining about your properties that look like this: `filter: alpha(opacity = 50);`, the same for other non-standard `opacity:` properties.

The fact of the matter is opacity wasn't standardized early enough...and to use it is hacky, it wont validate...either accept that it won't validate or remove it from all browsers that don't support the standard `opacity:` property, those are the two choices available.